# Receiving funding as a foreigner from NSF (for a foreign NGO)

Tags: funding, international, nsf

I was a university student in Russia but not finished my study because of discriminatory reasons. (I consider my missing professor's diploma as a fake document and Russia illegal.) So I have no even Bachelor diploma.

I continued the research I started while being in a university as an independent researcher.

I tried to obtain funding for research from NSF as an individual. But I was rejected with saying that it is because they don't provide funding for non-US individuals.

If I register an NGO in Kenya, am I eligible I to obtain NSF funding for that NGO for my research?

My girl in Kenya has 4 years university degree. Can I register her in NSF as my student, to become a co-researcher in the future?

Also, how much funding (I mean salary/stipend) ask for:

- me?
- my girl?

My research is very important (particularly for rich countries including the US). I believe it is equivalent of Nobel prize level (but not in a field where Nobel prizes are given).

Comment: https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/2012/nsf12070/nsf12070.jsp#cafo is unclear on this: "NSF rarely provides support to foreign organizations." But sometimes provides? Will they prefer a victim of discrimination like me?

Comment: Sorry, what? You seem to be an Israeli national, formerly of Russia, now in Kenya, so why are you pursuing funding from NSF? I think you're drastically misunderstanding NSF's mission statement. They provide funding to universities and research institutes in the US, not people working abroad, no matter how important their research.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim I am still in Israel. Please quote this mission statement as you refered to it. As I understand https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/2012/nsf12070/nsf12070.jsp#cafo they sometimes do provide funding for foreign organizations or do I misunderstand. Explain your comment in more details.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim And on why I don't seek funding for example in Russia. They provide funding only to people with diplomas. When I filed a lawsuit to a Russian court for monetary compensation for illegal discrimination, as it appeared the so called judge put the lawsuit into a trash can.

Comment: Sorry, it's not a mission statement that I read, it's just from working with NSF. That's just how NSF functions, they award grants to universities to carry out research proposed by their faculty. They don't fund independent researchers, and not overseas, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: And I wasn't asking about why you didn't apply for funding from Russia, I was asking why NSF, from a country you appear to have no ties to.

Comment: National Science Foundation is much more an arm of the US Government than it is a charitable foundation. Don’t let the name confuse you.